# Browser-based JS module import failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to implement reusable code blocks in JS. According to the documentation at [ExploringJS](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_overview-modules), the following approach should work:

```
<script language="javascript" type="module">
   import declarePasswordEventHandlers from '/pathTo/password_event_handlers.js';
</script>
<script language="javascript">
   $( 'document' ).ready( function() { 
      declarePasswordEventHandlers(); 
   });
</script>
```

The imported module looks like this:

```
export default function declarePasswordEventHandlers() { 
   // event handlers being declared
}
```

When I load the page, I get the following error:
[image: screenshot of error messages]

I've also tried:

```
<script language="javascript" type="module">
   import { declarePasswordEventHandlers } from '/pathTo/password_event_handlers.js';
</script>
<script language="javascript">
   $( 'document' ).ready( function() { 
       declarePasswordEventHandlers(); 
   });
</script>
```

and:

```
<script language="javascript" type="module">
   import * as passHandlerLib from '/pathTo/password_event_handlers.js';
</script>
<script language="javascript">
   $( 'document' ).ready( function() { 
      passHandlerLib.declarePasswordEventHandlers(); 
   });
</script>
```

Both used the selfsame export file as above, but with the default keyword removed from the export statement:

```
export function declarePasswordEventHandlers() { 
   // event handlers being declared
}
```

None of these approaches work; I get the same exact error shown in the attached screenshot.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have to move the import into the second script tag. A script tag can't have a body and a source

Comment: no joy. exact same error message.

Comment: Can you post the updated code?